# C# : how to accept two generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function which I want to convert the below Ping and Pong to generic type. Is it possible?

```
private Pong ReadDataFromApi(string url, Ping data)
{
    string url = "URL_TO_HIT";

    WebResponse response = Util.SendWebRequest<Ping>(url, data, 30000);

    var res = new Pong();
    if (response != null)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pong>(objText);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

I could convert to something below :

```
private T ReadDataFromApi(string url, T data)  T : class
{
    string url = "URL_TO_HIT";

    WebResponse response = Util.SendWebRequest<T>(url, data, 30000);

    var res = new Pong();
    if (response != null)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pong>(objText);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Not sure how to accept the Pong as a generic parameter.

Comment: use another name like `U` for the second parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
private TPong ReadDataFromApi<TPing, TPong>(string url, TPing data)
    where TPing : class
    where TPong : class,new() //You need to create instances of TPong
{
    WebResponse response = Util.SendWebRequest<TPing>(url, data, 30000);

    var res = new TPong(); //Create instance of TPong
    if (response != null)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TPong>(objText);
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like this

```
private TPong ReadDataFromApi<TPing,TPong>(string url, TPing data) 
        where TPing : class 
        where TPong : class, new()
```

Comment: If the OP already has types named `Ping` and `Pong` it would be better to not use them as the generic names.  Also general practice with generics is to put a capital T before the name, so `TPing` and `TPong` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: And one needs the `new()` constraint

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to that:

```
private TPong ReadDataFromApi<TPong, TPing>(string url, TPing data)  TPong : class, new() where TPing : class
{
    string url = "URL_TO_HIT";
    WebResponse response = Util.SendWebRequest<TPing>(url, data, 30000);

    var res = new TPong(); // USE TPong HERE
    if (response != null)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TPong>(objText); // AND HERE
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

With the `new()` constraint you ensure that the `TPong` has a default constructor. You need this to be able to do `res = new TPong()`;

And pass the generic parameter `TPong` to `DeserializeObject<TPong>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo<TOne, TTwo>() 
   where TOne : BaseOne
   where TTwo : BaseTwo

var fooObj = foo<Ping,Pong>(url, data);
```

[see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: Your example doesn't actually use either of the generic types in the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Your signature should be something like:

```
private T ReadDataFromApi<S,T>(string url, S data) where S : class where T : class
```

Then calling it equivalent to your original function would be something like:

```
var myPong = ReadDataFromApi<Ping,Pong>(url, data);
```

Your signature would be kind of similar to the one for [Func<T, TResult>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) for example

Comment: I assume you meant to use `T` as either the return type or the type of `data` instead of both as `S`.

Comment: @juharr: Whoops. Yes.